# No executable found matching command "dotnet-...dll" after issuing docker run command

Tags: docker

I created a simple aspnet core app to play with docker.
Placed Dockerfile and dockerignore inside the solution folder.

*Dockerfile:*

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
LABEL maintainer deic@gmail.com
WORKDIR /home/dejant/desktop/app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish ./ParallelDemo/ParallelDemo.csproj -o /publish/
WORKDIR /publishdocker 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/bin/ParallelDemo.dll"]
```

Steps leading to the failed container run can be seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Dockerfile the Entrypoint should simply define the executable to be used (a single file/command, not the full command). In your case you should change it to `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]` and add a CMD definition at the end of the file `CMD ["/bin/ParallelDemo.dll"]`. In essence what docker will do is actually execute `dotnet /bin/ParallelDemo.dll`

Also I noticed that you are changing WORKDIR to what appears to be a folder on your host machine. The WORKDIR in essence is like running cd /path/to/driectory **inside** the container filesystem. So you should just use the COPY to add the app folder to the image like so `COPY /home/dejant/desktop/app app`

I also don't know what the publish command really does, but I see that you also change the WORKDIR to /publishdocker and then in the ENTRYPOINT run a .dll thats in /bin/ folder, which in essence means that the last WORKDIR is unnecessary.

And I'm not a .NET developer, but I am assumint that the -o flag defines where you want your project to be published? So probably the .dll file is also located somewhere in that directory

So your Dockerfile becomes something like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build

LABEL maintainer deic@gmail.com

COPY /home/dejant/desktop/app /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish ./ParallelDemo/ParallelDemo.csproj -o /publish/

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]

CMD ["/THE/CORRECT/PATH/TO/YOUR/.DLL/LOCATION"] ## Replace with the proper value
```

---

**UPDATE**

And actually since you seem to intend to use this as part of a multi-stage build, then you probably would just want to build the application in the build image and then copy the .dll to a fresh image.

That would look aprox. like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build

LABEL maintainer deic@gmail.com

COPY /home/dejant/desktop/app /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish ./ParallelDemo/ParallelDemo.csproj -o /publish/

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2

COPY --from=build /THE/CORRECT/PATH/TO/YOUR/.DLL/LOCATION /app/ParallelDemo.dll

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]

CMD ["/app/ParallelDemo.dll"]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this stuff out, unfortunately I'm still missing something, the same error received...

Comment: You can try checking the docker image state by running `docker run -it --entrypoint sh --rm pa1` and checking if the .dll file is in the correct location. It will allow you to use shell inside the container your image creates so you will be able to also check if manually running the command works.

Comment: Can you be more precise, what shall I do when I enter the shell inside the container?

Comment: After you are running the shell inside the container you can use `cd /app` to see if the .dll is there

Comment: If it's there you can try to run `dotnet /app/ParallelDemo.dll` manually and see if that works

Comment: On a sidenote - for the final image you might want to use a different image, as the SDK sounds like something necessary for development/build process but probably is not needed when you actually execute the application. I might be wrong though. Not a .NET developer